# converting object to string

Tags: c#, matlab, object, tostring

I use this code for calling a matlab function in C#

```
Object b;
matlab.Feval("fun444",(int)1,out b,(double)(10));
label1.Text = b.ToString();`
```

it works and I could saw my answer in b using debugging mode . 
I want to display his number but it returns to me : system.object[]
How can I display the double I saw in the debugger?

Comment: system.object[] tells me that's it's an array not a single object

Comment: thank you it works, but woh can I get a 2*2 matrix as output label1.Text = ((object[])b)[0,1].ToString() I try it but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matlab.Feval gives you an array of one element, you can get it like this :

```
label1.Text = ((object[])b)[0].ToString()
```

Comment: thank you it works, but woh can I get a 2*2 matrix as output label1.Text = ((object[])b)[0,1].ToString() I try it but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

You have an array instead of a single object.

You'll need to do something like this... 
Edit: I didn't see you were setting a textbox the first time I looked at your code.

```
label1.Text = b[0].ToString();
```